# Integration by differentiation with respect to a parameter question.

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having a lot of trouble solving this question via the differentiating with respect to a parameter method. I can get the correct result for the integral containing sine, but I'm totally lost when it comes to evaluating the integral containing cosine. Here's the problem statement:

Given:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \sin(kx) \ dx = \frac{k}{a^2+k^2}$$

evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-ax}\sin(kx) \ dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-ax} \cos(kx) \ dx$.

This is the last question in the 2nd chapter of 'Basic Training in Mathematics' by Shankar.
Any help would be appreciated, I've been tearing my hair out all day with this.

Comment: You'll get a lot more help if you typeset your question using MathJax rather than just posting a link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Have you considered differentiating:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \sin(kx) \ dx = \frac{k}{a^2+k^2}$$

with respect to $k$ instead? :-)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Abhi, differentiating w.r.t. $k$ will give you a direct answer. We have,

$$\frac {d}{dk} \left(\frac {k}{a^{2}+ k^{2}}\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \cdot \partial_{k}\sin(kx) dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-ax} \cos(kx) dx = \boxed{\frac {a^{2}-k^{2}}{(a^{2}+k^{2})^{2}}}$$

Differentiating with respect to $a$ gives the value of the other integral -

$$-\frac {d}{da}\left(\frac {k}{a^{2}+ k^{2}}\right) = -\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(kx) \cdot \partial_{a}(e^{-ax})dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-ax} \sin(kx) dx = \boxed {\frac{2ak}{(a^{2}+k^{2})^{2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{\on{u}\pars{a,k} \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-ax}\sin\pars{kx}\,\dd x}$ which satisfies
$\ds{\on{u}_{aa}\pars{a,k} + \on{u}_{kk}\pars{a,k} = 0}$.

It has the general solution
$$\on{u}\pars{a,k} =
\on{f}\pars{a + k\,\ic} + \on{g}\pars{a - k\,\ic}
$$

Then,
\begin{align}
0 & = \on{u}\pars{a,0} = \on{f}\pars{a} + \on{g}\pars{a}
\implies\on{g}\pars{a} = -\on{f}\pars{a}
\end{align}
The general solution is reduced to
\begin{equation}
\on{u}\pars{a,k} =
\on{f}\pars{a + k\,\ic} - \on{f}\pars{a - k\ic}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Moreover, $\ds{{1 \over a^{2}} = \on{u}_{k}\pars{a,0} =
\on{f}'\pars{a}\ic -
\bracks{\on{f}'\pars{a}\pars{-\ic}} =
2\on{f}'\pars{a}\ic}$
$\ds{\implies
\on{f}\pars{a} = {\ic \over 2a} + \underline{\mbox{a constant}}}$

and ( see (\ref{1}) )
$$
\on{u}\pars{a,k} = {\ic \over 2\pars{a + k\,\ic}} -
{\ic \over 2\pars{a - k\,\ic}} =
\bbx{k \over a^{2} + k^{2}} \\
$$